# Saving pivot cache of an Excel table

Tags: java, excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel file with a pivot table in it. I would like to process the original data behind the pivot, but it's from an external source and I don't have access to that.

I would like to save/read the pivot cache of this table in Java. Do you know any framework which would allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could call showdetail in VBA on the grand total of the pivot table to extract the original data table to a new sheet. From there you could export it to a csv to play with however you like.

```
Sub ShowGrandTotalDetail()
   Range(Split(Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Address, ":")(1)).showdetail = True
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
      Filename:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Test.csv", _
      FileFormat:=xlCSV
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Where "A3" refers to any cell in the pivot table.